# How can I change the cache type of DSR using NS2

Tags: adhoc, ns2

There are three types of cache at DSR. Mobicache, link cache and simplecache. Mobicache is the cache that is used by default in the DSR. I want to change from mobicache to  to link cache. How can I  do that using NS2.